# Bus error: 10. No errors when compiling

Tags: c, macos, unix, bus-error

So basically when I compile my code with a GCC compiler I get no error or warnings, but when I input the first piece of data it says:

```
Bus error: 10.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think The problem is coming from `void anagramGrouping` (the last function). I also included the rest of the code to help follow the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Row 2
#define col 20

int wordCount = 0;
int groupCount = 0;
char wordList[Row][col];
char group[Row][col];

// this is where prototypes go
void sortword(char word[col]);                 
void anagramGrouping(char word[col], char copy[col]);   
void resetGroup();                                   

int main() {
    int i; // used in for loop to 'get' the strings 
    char word[col];

    resetGroup();

    for (i = 0; i < Row; i++) {
        scanf("%s", word);
        sortword(word);
        wordCount++;
    }
}

void resetGroup() {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        strcpy(group[i], " ");
}

void sortword(char word[col]) {
    int i = 0; 
    char temp;
    char copy[col]; // used to store a copy of the original word

    strcpy(copy, word);

    while (word[i] != '\0') {
        int j = i + 1;

        while (word[j] != '\0') {
            if (word[j] < word[i]) {
                temp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[j];
                word[j] = temp;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    anagramGrouping(word,copy);
}

void anagramGrouping(char word[col], char copy[col]) {
    int n;

    if (wordCount == 0) {
        strcpy(group[0], copy);
    }

    for (n = 0; n <= groupCount; n++) {
        if (strcmp(group[n], word) == 0) {
            strcpy(group[n], copy);
        } else {
            groupCount++;
            strcpy(group[groupCount], copy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run your program in valgrind or gdb to see which line triggers the crash.

Comment: Sorry to not be of more help, but try checking your pointers / dereferencing.

Comment: Your code is very badly presented. Fix the indentation and remove the useless `// end of function` comments.

Comment: I cleaned up the indentation of my code. Also, i've never heard of valgrind or gdb before.

Comment: You realize that `*(word+i)` is just `word[i]`, right?  The latter would certainly be a lot clearer.

Comment: Your `anagramGrouping` function seems to be the problem.  Each time you find a mismatch, you are increasing `groupCount`.  In this example, it is not allowed to exceed 2 (or even to reach it), yet it almost certainly does, which will cause a memory error.

Comment: Here's a simple thing you can do to debug this:  In `anagramGrouping`, right after the line `groupCount++;`, check to see if `groupCount >= Row`, and if it is, print an error and exit.  I believe you will then see the error message in place of the bus error.

Comment: Trying that does exit and print an error message. any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to re-think your algorithm.  You are storing words into `group`, but you have only allocated enough room to store  `Row` words (in this example, 2).  So, what was your intent?  Do you want to store more than that?  If so, then you need to change your declaration to allow for more.  If not, then you need to debug your algorithm.  Basically you need to step back and decide what you want it to do.

Comment: I ended up using a break in the loop , specifically within the else statement  and this seemed to fix the problem

Comment: Well, hopefully what you have is correct now, but my suggestion is to first understand your algorithm before trying to implement it.  In this case, `groupCount` must never exceed `Row - 1`, i.e. it must never exceed 1, or you will index out of the declared bounds of `group`.

Answer (score -1):

For starters, change all

```
sortword (char word[col])
```

to

```
sortword (char *word)
```

and all

```
anagramGrouping (char word[col], char copy[col])
```

to

```
anagramGrouping (char *word, char *copy)
```

When you pass `char copy[col]`, you are passing a `character array`, which when passed as a function parameter is converted to a *pointer*. (you will hear the phrase *"decays to a pointer"*, which isn't entirely correct, but is used often to mean the same thing). This isn't the problem causing the `bus error`, but will make your code much more readable.

Next, your `bus error` is generally due to the misuse of a pointer value which when the value is taken, falls outside the allowable memory range for your program, usually in the *system* area causing the `bus error`. Looking over your code, it is hard to tell which of the many issues may be the exact cause. However, a likely culprit is:

```
for(n=0; n <= groupCount; n++)
{
    if ( strcmp(group[n],word) ==0 )
    {
        strcpy(group[n],copy);
    }
    else
    {
        groupCount++;
        strcpy(group[groupCount],copy);
    }
}
```

Where running through a debugger, you will quickly find that `groupCount` grows well beyond `1` causing `strcpy(group[groupCount],copy)` to write beyond the end of the `char group[Row][col];`. Where the allowable row values are limited to `0-1` as you `#define Row 2`.

To limit the copies to the allowable range, change the loop criteria to:

```
for (n = 0; n < Row; n++) {
```

A further cleanup of your code could look as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define Row 2
#define col 20

int wordCount = 0;
int groupCount = 0;
char wordList[Row][col];
char group[Row][col];

void sortword (char *word);                 
void anagramGrouping (char *word, char *copy);   
void resetGroup();                                   

int main (void) {

    int i;
    char word[col] = "";

    resetGroup();

    for (i = 0; i < Row; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%s", word);
        sortword (word);
        wordCount++;
    }

    return 0; /* main is a function of type 'int' and returns a value */
}

void resetGroup()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < Row; i++)
        *group[i] = 0;
}

void sortword (char *word)
{
    int i = 0; 
    char temp;
    char copy[col] = "";

    strcpy (copy, word);

    while (word[i]) {
        int j = i + 1;
        while (word[j]) {
            if(word[j] < word[i]) {
                temp = word[i];
                word[i] = word[j];
                word[j] = temp;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    anagramGrouping (word,copy);
}

void anagramGrouping (char *word, char *copy)
{
    int n;

    if (!wordCount)
        strcpy (group[0],copy);

    for (n = 0; n < Row; n++) {
        if (strcmp (group[n], word) == 0)
            strcpy(group[n],copy);
        else {
            groupCount++;
            strcpy (group [groupCount],copy);
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The whole nonsense about not passing an array is irrelevant to the question and also bad advice. `char word[col]` is much more readable and much more type safe than `char* word`. If anything, the function should be changed to `sortword (size_t col, char word[col])`, to make it independent of the macro and even more type safe.

Comment: Also regarding your remark about decay being the incorrect term... conversion is much more incorrect, since the term conversion, as used by the standard, is something that takes place in runtime. Array decay does not. The C standard actually uses the word "adjust" to describe this (6.7.6.3): "A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to
type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation."

Comment: Good point. `'adjust'` it is -- which after being done leaves you with an array converted to a pointer `:)`

Comment: @Lundin I disagree with your comments regarding whether to show an array or pointer in the parameter list. Since the array is `'adjusted'`, the function does not receive an array, it receives a *pointer-to-the-array* which makes the pointer a clear indication regarding what is available to the function.

Comment: The advantage of the array style is that it enables more type safety so that good compilers or external, static analysers can flag type-related warnings. Apart from that, it is mainly a style issue, but if so, the C99 committee doesn't agree with your choice of style. Otherwise they wouldn't have invented all those mildly useful things that can be put inside array style function parameters. If your preferred style is correct, then why did C99 invent array qualifiers `func (int a[const 10])`, "least n items" `func (int a[static 10])`, and VLA prototypes `func (int, int [*])`?